# Flatten JSON Object in Snowflake

Tags: sql, arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I have a question about using the flatten function in Snowflake. I'm having trouble with extracting data from following path data:performance: of the following JSON-object:

```
   {
"data": {
    "metadata": {
        "id": "001",
        "created_at": "2020-01-01"
    },
    "performance": {
        "2020-01-01": {
            "ad_performances": [{
                "ad": "XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m",
                "ad_impressions": 1,
                "clicks": 0,
                "device": "-3",
                "total_net_amount": 0
            }, {
                "ad": "XoGKkgmFlHa3V5xj",
                "ad_impressions": 17,
                "clicks": 0,
                "device": "-4",
                "total_net_amount": 0
            }, {
                "ad": "XoGKkgmFlHa3V5xj",
                "ad_impressions": 5,
                "clicks": 0,
                "device": "-5",
                "total_net_amount": 0
            }, {
                "ad": "XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m",
                "ad_impressions": 19,
                "clicks": 0,
                "device": "-2",
                "total_net_amount": 0
            }, {
                "ad": "XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m",
                "ad_impressions": 5,
                "clicks": 0,
                "device": "-1",
                "total_net_amount": 0
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Desired result is a table with the "date" (2020-01-01), "ad" and "impressions".
I tried to achieve the desired result with:

```
select
   key::date                           as date
  ,f.value:performances:ad             as performances_array
  ,f.value:performances:impressions    as performances_array
from <table>, lateral flatten (input => CLMN:performances) f;
```

but I´m not able to extract data from the "performance-array". Can someone help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you check your JSON (it seems it misses some commas etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 2 LATERAL FLATTENs are required to extract the rows

```
select
   a.key::date as ad_date,
   b.value:ad::varchar as ad,
   b.value:ad_impressions::int as impressions
from j
, lateral flatten(input => v:data:performance) a
, lateral flatten(input => a.value:ad_performances) b;
```

| AD_DATE | AD | IMPRESSIONS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | XoGKkgmFlHa3V5xj | 17 |
| 2020-01-01 | XoGKkgmFlHa3V5xj | 5 |
| 2020-01-01 | XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m | 19 |
| 2020-01-01 | XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m | 5 |

If you want to aggregate the data by ad date and ad,

```
with r as
(
  select
    a.key::date as ad_date,
    b.value:ad::varchar as ad,
    b.value:ad_impressions::int as impressions
  from j
  , lateral flatten(input => v:data:performance) a
  , lateral flatten(input => a.value:ad_performances) b
)
select ad_date, ad, sum(impressions) as impressions
from r
group by ad_date, ad;
```

| AD_DATE | AD | IMPRESSIONS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m | 25 |
| 2020-01-01 | XoGKkgmFlHa3V5xj | 22 |

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one?

```
select  f.KEY date, 
l.VALUE:"ad"  as performances_array,
l.VALUE:"impressions"  as performances_array
from mydata, lateral flatten (input => CLMN:data.performance ) f,
lateral flatten (input => f.VALUE ) s,
lateral flatten (input => s.VALUE ) l
;

+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    DATE    | PERFORMANCES_ARRAY | PERFORMANCES_ARRAY |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 2020-01-01 | "XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m" |                  1 |
| 2020-01-01 | "XoGKkgmFlHa3V5xj" |                 17 |
| 2020-01-01 | "XoGKkgmFlHa3V5xj" |                    |
| 2020-01-01 | "XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m" |                 19 |
| 2020-01-01 | "XoGKkgcy7V3BDm6m" |                  5 |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I had to use multiple FLATTENs to loop in arrays.

Comment: Hey, thank you! Perhaps I poorly described my expected result.
I expect four rows - each one for each value for "ad".

Comment: @jules118 It returns 5 rows, but you may filter out NULL values, aggregate the result, or select only the first one etc

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! Also good to see you first query!